# Как добавить текст на фото без GD Library (или оптимизировать его), средствами PHP?

Tags: php, изображения, gd

Есть необходимость динамически генерировать текст на фото, фото может быть любого размера, текст при этом, должен быть в верхнем правом углу. Текущий скрипт, построенный на основе GD Library это учитывает. Однако, после отработки, конечное изображение весит во много раз больше чем начальное.

[image: Как можно заметить, размер итогового изображения сильно увеличился]

Как можно заметить, размер итогового изображения сильно увеличился.

Оригинал: **+-154kb** x После обработки: **1 711kb**

*Вопрос частично решён.* Нужно выводить Jpeg вместо Png с качеством, примерно 75%.
Но всё равно размер выходит где-то на 100kb больше чем оригинал, можно ли как-то сжать её ещё сильнее без сильной потери в качестве?

Comment: если вам без GD то смотрите в сторону других библиотек, а-ля ImageMagick. Если хотите текущее оптимизировать, то приложите код.

Comment: Могу приложить код, да хотелось бы максимально оптимизировать, поскольку нужно будет динамически генерить "ачивки" (плашки) в виде jpeg картинок, там будет много текста, он будет кешироваться, но генериться должен на лету по заданным критериям. Хотелось бы удобно группировать текст на обложке.